# Limit of the smallest eigenvalue of a random Gram matrix $XX^T/n$.

Tags: matrices, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems, random-matrices, singular-values

Let $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$ be a random matrix with independent rows which satisfy that $\mathbb{E}(X_iX_i^T) = I_d$ and $\mathbb{E}(X_i) = 0$. The [results](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.6188.pdf) of P. Yaskov provide conditions on when the minimum eigenvalue of the covariance matrix $X^TX/n\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ is lower bounded in the case that $d/n \to \rho <1$.

Is it possible to obtain conditions on when the smallest eigenvalue of $XX^T/n\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ (so the smallest positive eigenvalue of $X^TX/n$)  is lower bounded in the case that $d/n \to \rho \geq 1$.

Comment: gram matrix $\to$ Gram matrix (it weighs in this way)

Comment: Thank you @JeanMarie

Comment: Connected: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1267414/305862